# How do you make and use an XIB file for a table view cell, rather than just using a cell "in" the table view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, swift5

In a normal storyboard, table views come "with" embedded cells. Simply set "Dynamic Prototypes" to 1 (or more):

[image]

You then use the those cells in your view controller simply with

```
...cellForRowAt

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
     withIdentifier:"YourCellClassID", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass
```

Where `YourCellClass` is the class of the table view cell,

and the string "YourCellClassID" is just

the **"Identifier"** set in the **Attributes Inspector (nowadays the **5th** button)** of the storyboard.

(Be careful to NOT use the "restoration identifier" on the *4th* button, identity inspector, which sounds the same but is unrelated.)

[image]

But what if you want to **use an XIB file**?

Instead of using one of the prototypes "in" the table view in storyboard?

If you use an XIB file, you can use the **same cell in different tables**.

How to do it?

Comment: .. so I posted a "QA style" question & answer.  Hope it helps some young programmers who grew up in the "no nib files" era!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step 1, to make a cell-style XIB file

In current (2020) Xcode there's no direct button to create a table view cell -style XIB file.

The secret is

1. create a 'Cocoa Touch Class', select UITableViewCell
2. and ALSO select 'create XIB file'

> [image]
>
> [image]

You now have a cell-style XIB file, TesteCell.xib in the example.

(Feel free to delete TesteCell.swift if you don't need it.)

## Step 2, add the `register#UINib` code in `viewDidLoad`

If you now try this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
              withIdentifier: "TesteCellID",
              for: indexPath) as! TesteCell
```

In fact it does ***not*** work.

In `viewDidLoad`, you must add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // We will be using an XIB file, rather than
    // just a cell "in" the table view on storyboard
    tableView.register(
        UINib(nibName: "filename without suffix", bundle: nil),
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier in attributes inspector"
    )
}
```

In the example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // We will be using an XIB file...
    tableView.register(
        UINib(nibName: "TesteCell", bundle: nil),
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "TesteCellID")
}
```

[image: descrip]

And that's how you do it.

## Summary

1. New file - cocoa touch class - subclass of table cell - do select 'also create XIB file'
2. In viewDidLoaed, register the XIB file using,
3. The file name (no suffix) and the identifier
4. You're done, you can now refer to the cell in the normal way in `dequeueReusableCell`

Comment: Except none of it is a trick, and everyone else has known (and done) this for years.

Comment: Hi @matt !  You seem agitated about use of the word "trick", I took it out (generally, feel absolutely free to edit posts that agitate you.  Particularly QA style posts).  Regarding your second comment, you seem to be basically saying "this is too simple for the site". I don't really follow you there - many of the millions of QA on the site are pretty basic.  If you have a clear point to make please explain?  Should the QA be deleted ??

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to delete the comment; I wasn't meaning to be disparaging (or embarrassing), just answering as best I could the question you posed me (involving "should").

Comment: thanks!  anyway, by all means post a better answer (for newbs), your answers are always the Best !  I'll just delete mine

Comment: No need, what you're saying is not wrong, it's just kind of old, is all I'm saying.